# convert java code to c# code (hexString To ByteArray)

Tags: java, c#, arrays

Hello I have a code in Java I want to make it to code in C # but I'm having a problem:

This code (func):

```
DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary (temp);
```

I'm looking for a replacement in `C#`

On the other hand
I have the full code should do this in Java but also where I encountered a problem in this code:

```
public static byte [] hexStringToByteArray (String s)
{
    int len ​​= s.Length;
    byte [] data = new byte [len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i <len; i + = 2)
    {
        data [i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit (s.charAt (i), 16) << 4)
                                     + Character.digit (s.charAt (i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler does not recognize the

```
Character.digit (s.charAt (i)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you used `Google translate` for that last line from hebrew. right? :P

Comment: genius!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I live in Modiin, btw. (I'm also trying to answer your question right now)

Comment: Beer Sheva :) Thanks!

Comment: did you work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a `hex` string to a `byte` array, you can use:

```
public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string s)
{
    int len = s.Length;
    byte[] data = new byte[len/ 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    {
        data[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return data;
}
```